# IBM MQ mqrc 2042

Tags: c++, ibm-mq, mq

Have an issue with one of MQ queue, where multiple C++ program is trying to access the queue from different host and they receiving 2042 error. I can see they are opening the queue as exclusive INPUT "INPUT(EXCL)" and APPLTAG(mqmessage). 
From queue manager side queue is set to shareable and DEFSOPT(SHARED) all looks good.

What are the changes required from C++ program not to open as EXCL input? So that multiple user can access?

Thanks

Comment: Look at `MQOO_` open options.  Remove the exclusive or switch to shared.  Default if nothing is specified is the queue's `DEFSOPT`.

Comment: You mean on MQ side? Its set to SHARED already.

Comment: No i was answering your question.

Comment: In your C++ code, change MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE to MQOO_INPUT_SHARED and then all processes will be able to get messages from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openoptions of the C++ application have to be modified.If your c++ application is having "MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE" as one of the OpenOptions then it has to be removed.
Check this [MQOPEN options for removing messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026040_.htm)

Following stackoverflow answer is also on the similar lines
[IBM WebSphere MQ 2042 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965468/ibm-websphere-mq-2042-error)